# Can anyone explain lift before the experiment?

Tags: lift

The sensors on the wing tell me lower pressure above the wing, the smoke visualization tells me the air stream is faster when flowing over the curve. But can anyone tell me why they behave like that before the experiments?

Comment: For the same reason that the speed of light is 300'000 km/s: this is just how it works the particular universe where we live  Anyway the physical/mathematical explanation of that phenomenon is termed "momentum conservation"

Comment: The navier-stokes equations perfectly explain lift, but good luck a) solving them, or b) explaining them to a class of curious fifth graders

Comment: Before the experiments? It feels like a lot of context is missing.